# CSS Background 100% Issue

Tags: css, background

I am new still a beginner to CSS and I have been having problems with getting my background to fill the age. I know `contain` and `cover` won't help me but even things like `background-size` and the `width`and `height` commands aren't helping.

```
body {
   background-image:url(X.png);
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
}
```

Comment: no it won't `cover` only expands the image not stretching it

Comment: For percentage to work on `background-size`, you would need to give `html { height: 100% }` so that the body can inherit its height. [Like this example](https://jsbin.com/vayizi/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: yeah I needed to day min height = 100%

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try add these style below:

```
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;

background-size: cover;
-ms-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
```

It should work, please check my jsfiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/chris_poetfarmer/9xa35pwp/

Comment: This answer is a huge moonshot. `background-size: cover` is [hugely supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts) and doesn't really require prefixes anymore, the `min-height: 100%` and `height: 100%` are not both needed, only one or the other depending on what you are trying to achieve, and `width: 100%` and `min-width: 100%` are not required at all as html and body already take up 100% width. This is demonstrated in [this example here](https://jsbin.com/wuzura/edit?css,output), only the `html {height: 100%}` is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `html` instead of body. `cover` should work, but it may depend on the browser as to how it act's for instance you may need to use `-moz-background-size:cover` if the browser is mozilla based.